# Poincaré duality and Galois action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Poincaré duality says that under nice situation we have a canonical perfect pairing

$$ P : H_c^r(X, \mathscr{F}) \times H^{2d - r}(X, \mathscr{F}^\vee(d)) \to \mathbb{Z}/n.$$

I want to show that this is compatible with the Galois action:
Precisely,

> Let $k$ be a field, $\overline{k}$ a separable closure of $k$, $G$ the abstract Galois group, $X_0$ a smooth $k$-variety ( = separated scheme of finite type of "geometrically pure" of dimension $d$), $n$ an integer which is invertible in $k$, $\mathscr{F}_0$ a locally constant sheaf on $X_0$, and $X = X_0 \times \overline{k}$, $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{F}_0 \times \overline{k}.$
>   Then is the Poincare pairing 
>   $$H_c^r(X, \mathscr{F}) \times H^{2d - r}(X, \mathscr{F}^\vee(d)) \to \mathbb{Z}/n.$$
>   compatible with the action of $G$?

I can't find any references mentioning it.
But Deligne's "Weil I" uses this compatibility.

(8.6.6) of Fu's étale cohomology theory says that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field and if $X$ is proper and if $\mathscr{F} = \mathbb{Z}/n$, then $P(a,b) = Tr(a \cup b)$.
Now I know that the cup product is compatible with the Galois action (i.e., $\sigma a \cup \sigma b = \sigma (a \cup b)$), and that the trace map is compatible with the Galois action.
So in this case, the Poincaré duality is compatible with the Galois action.
How about the general case?
i.e., for non-proper $X_0$, non-perfect $k$ and for general locally constant sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, is the Poincaré duality compatible?

It seems that Weil I says that "Poincare dual = $Tr$(cup product)" holds even for non-proper schemes and for general locally constant sheaf $\mathscr{F}$.
However, if this is true, I don't know the definition of cup product for compact support cohomology.

And I don't know about non-perfect case at all.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Etale cohomology does not change when you base change by a purely inseparable extension, so you can always replace the base field with its perfection.